# Emailing professor about final exam as a Master's student

Tags: exams

When you email professors to ask if you can see your final exam, they usually are reluctant to show you the exam. So, they tell you that as long as you pass the course, there is no need to worry.

But, I want to know what I did incorrectly, and also see if there is any grading error because I think I did better on the exam than my approximate exam grade I calculated based on the final grade (the final exam grade was not posted).

The professor did not post the solutions to the exam or the final exam grade.

How should I ask to see the final exam to maximize the chances that the professor will agree to send a copy of the exam?

Do professors have to show the exam or exam grade or is there no obligation?

It would also be fine for me to ask for the solutions to the exam if I realize that my exam grade should be lower than what I think after reading the solutions.

Comment: "because they often don't grade it fully" citation needed. Not my experience.

Comment: The question is missing a country tag. In some countries it is common that students can have a look at the graded exams and even try to explain their solutions to get additional points if the grader did not see why their solution is also correct.

Comment: I did not downvote. But, I think your question may be downvoted because you wrote "**...they usually are reluctant to show you the exam because they often don't grade it fully**". Did you mean to write "**...because they have not finished grading all exams from all students in the class yet**" ? If that is what you meant to say, then you could edit your question to improve the approval rating for your question.

Comment: Whether there is an obligation depends on your country (and sometimes institution within the country), this question at minimum needs a country tag. Even if there is an obligation they probably do not need to email it to you or show you solutions, only allow you to view it with them in their office.

Comment: @Job_September_2020 If the final exam is pass/fail, the instructor will sometimes rapidly establish if a particular student obviously fails or obviously passes, and thus not always grade this exam in details; only for the more marginal cases would the instructor mark the copy in details.  I certainly know of *some* courses where this is the case, and I suspect there are many more.  I do not know how prevalent this is and so I think the statements by the OP are overly general, although they might reflect local practices.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero, Yes, you are right about those pass/fail classes. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Job_September_2020 it is admittedly not clear if this is the case for the OP.  If the exam is not a simple pass/fail and there is a letter grade or a numerical grade attached to the course credits, I would hope an instructor would mark every copy in full.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero, I agree on all points. I would hope the OP would clarify his post.

Comment: When I did my undergraduate studies in germany there was always a special timeslot for viewing your exams ("Klausureinsicht"). The timeslot was posted by the grading professor, and you could go there, have a look at your exam and discuss with the professor/postdocs who graded the course. Maybe you should have a look at your universities rules, maybe they have some formal provision for viewing the exams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where I work:

1. students have a right to see their copy of the final exam; this does not extend to accessing a copy of the solution to the exam (which are rarely posted) or the marking rubric, although most instructors have no issue with discussing the contents of the exam copy with the student.
2. the actual booklets used to write the final exam must remain with the instructor and “safely stored” for one year in case a student files an appeal and some exam copies must be recovered for comparison.

Various institutions have their own rule book but I would be surprised if an instructor agreed to mail you your copy: it is too dangerous if you challenge the final grade.  You will likely have better luck asking for a meeting to discuss your exam.

Answer (score 2):

I don't set the rules universally, but ethically, you are entitled to full information about how you were graded. That doesn't, however, imply that you should be sent a copy of the exam.

But you should, in principle, be entitled to visit the professor and have any deficiencies explained to you. But changes in grade aren't very likely after such a meeting.

Again, rules vary, but they should favor transparency.

Answer (score 1):

> How should I ask to see the final exam to maximize the chances that the professor will agree to send a copy of the exam?

At my former university, you can certainly request to meet with your professors to review your exam papers and grades. You can simply contact the professors via emails or phone calls.

They may be too busy right at the end of the semesters. But, eventually all professors will find some available time and place to show you your exam papers, and they may even discuss the solutions to the exams with you, and answer all your questions/concerns.

---

Usually, the professors want to finish the grading of the whole class first before they meet with any student to discuss the individual grade for that student. That is understandable.

The length of time to finish the grading of a whole class may depend on how many classes and how many students your professors have.

Maybe, you can wait for some time from a few days to a week after you finish the exam, and then start asking the professors about the grades ?